# how to check if two set of statements are transitive and reflexive given a mapping of words

Tags: python

Given 2 sentences, and a mapping of words with its synonyms, I want to write a program to determine if the sentences are similar. 2 sentences are similar iff they have the same number of words and each of the corresponding words are synonyms. Be sure to handle the case for symmetric and transitive relations between synonyms. E.g. synonyms map is:

```
[(“a”, “b”), (“a”, “c”), (“a”, “d”), (“b”, “e”), (“f”, “e”), (“g”, “h”)]
```

Then sentences `“a e g”` and `“f c h”` are synonyms. Example:

```
Input S1: “a e g” S2: “f c h” 
Map: [(“a”, “b”), (“a”, “c”), (“a”, “d”), (“b”, “e”), (“f”, “e”), (“g”, “h”)]
Output: True
```

Explanation: `“a”` and `“f”` are synonym because `“a”` and `“b”` are synonyms, `“f”` and `“e”` are synonyms and `“b”` and `“e”` are synonyms. Similarly `“c”` and `“e”` are synonyms and `“g”` and `“h”` are synonyms.

I have tried this set of code:

```
synonyms = [('a','b'), ('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','e'), ('f','e'), ('g','h')]

def transitive(sequence):
    for a,b in sequence:
        for c,d in sequence:
            if b==c and (a,d) not in sequence:
                return True

    return False

def symmetric(sequence):
    for x,y in sequence:
        for a,z in sequence:
            if y == a and x == z:
                return True
    return False

def main(input1, input2):

    if len(input1) == len(input2):
        for a in input1:    
            for b in input2:
                if transitive(synonyms) and symmetric(synonyms):
                    c = "True"
                else:
                    c = "False"

        for a in input1 and input2:
        # for b in input2:
            if transitive(synonyms) and symmetric(synonyms):
                c = "True"

            else:
                c = "False"
        print(c)

    else:
        print("False")                      
first = input("Enter first statement: \n")
second = input("Enter second statement: \n")
main(first,second)
```

I am not able to think for the logic to compare the two strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility. Since you have a [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), you can think of the [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) that are formed from it. Basically, you can create sets such that all words that are synonym with each other are together. Or, if you prefer to think of it in terms of graphs, you can consider your tuples as edges of an undirected graph and find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

You can do that like this:

```
def make_word_classes(synom):
    # List of classes
    word_classes = []
    for w1, w2 in synom:
        # Go through existing classes
        for wcls in word_classes:
            # If one of the words is already in the current class
            if w1 in wcls or w2 in wcls:
                # Add both words and continue to next pair of words
                wcls.add(w1)
                wcls.add(w2)
                break
        else:  # Note this else goes with the for loop, not the if block
            # If there was no matching class, add a new one
            word_classes.append({w1, w2})
    return word_classes

synom = [("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("a", "d"), ("b", "e"), ("f", "e"), ("g", "h")]
word_classes = make_word_classes(synom)
print(word_classes)
# [{'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'e'}, {'h', 'g'}]
```

With that, it is easy to tell whether two sentences are equivalent. You just have to check that each pair of words is equal or belong to the same equivalence class:

```
def sentences_are_equivalent(s1, s2, word_classes):
    # Split into words
    l1 = s1.split()
    l2 = s2.split()
    # If they have different sizes they are different
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False
    # Go through each pair of corresponding words
    for w1, w2 in zip(l1, l2):
        # If it is the same word then it is okay
        if w1 == w2:
            continue
        # Go through list of word classes
        for wcls in word_classes:
            # If both words are in the same class it is okay
            if w1 in wcls and w2 in wcls:
                # Continue to next pair of words
                break
        else:  # Again, this else goes with the for loop
            # If no class contains the pair of words
            return False
    return True

s1 = "a e g"
s2 = "f c h"
print(sentences_are_equivalent(s1, s2, word_classes))
# True
```